# Flow types throwing error on seemingly unrelated types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have the following [`flow`](https://flow.org/en/docs/) code ([available here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAygjgVwIYCcI2E40C8UDeAUFFAG5IA2CEAXFAHYIC2ARhCgDSEC+A3IYVCQoASXrYU9SvGRooeIiXJVaDZmxRQAPmooUufARAAeYAPYpgUAGYJ6AY2ABLM-SgBzCMACySYwAoAZ0RUCEC6AEEUFCQQAB4xCSkKGVCAPm0oKJj41LQMLAg0gEo6RlZ2AmISKDRgBEkoYNkwgDo0ABMEewh-WwdnV38kKDL1dg4oFlHRcXZkvOgdRYLsUrUKzUUakidrKH8WVuVqeRw8Rj1iqp2duoa3JH5bqG4oCApA6G2X+8bfYAAC1aTD8w0mRxOEGKz1u3GqJG4kwADDCeAIgA)):

```
type SquareState = {
  value: number,
};

type InternalSquare = {
  value: number | null,
};

export function getMax(squares: Array<InternalSquare> | Array<SquareState>): number {
   return squares.reduce(function(a : number, b : InternalSquare | SquareState): number {
    if (b.value === null) {
      return a;
    } else {
      return Math.max(a, b.value);
    }
  }, 0);
}
```

Which is generating this error:

```
 9: export function getMax(squares: Array<InternalSquare> | Array<SquareState>): number {
                                                             ^ number [1] is incompatible with null [2] in property `value`.
   References:
   2:   value: number,
               ^ [1]
   6:   value: number | null,
                        ^ [2]
```

As far as I understand, there should be no error, because there's a guard against `null`. The code works fine with either:

```
export function getMax(squares: Array<SquareState>):  number
```

or

```
export function getMax(squares: Array<InternalSquare>): number
```

But not with `Array<SquareState> | Array<InternalSquare>`

Also, if I [replace the reduce with a for loop](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAygjgVwIYCcI2E40C8UDeAUFFAG5IA2CEAXFAHYIC2ARhCgDSEC+A3IYVCQoASXrYU9SvGRooeIiXJVaDZmxRQAPmooUufARAAeYAPYpgUAGYJ6AY2ABLM-SgBzCMACySYwAoAZ0RUCEC6AEEUFCQQAB4xCSkKGVCAPm0oKJj41LQMLAg0gEo6RlZ2AmIyVCgmP3koAAZ+EmsLf3JNJ0amqF4oHrioYNkwgDoKCHp3YAALfsGoAGpl4qqSTadrKCCQtECAbScAXXHlankcPEY9dcVNzftXZ0YIVsfuKAgKQOgHx51Bp4Xzzcb1AIQjgjfZhY5nC4QYofTbcapokhoYAISRA4z8NGEIA), it works:

```
export function getMax(squares: Array<InternalSquare> | Array<SquareState>): number {
  var max = 0;
  for(var i = 0 ; i < squares.length ; i ++) {
     if (squares[i].value === null) {
       continue;
     } else {
       max = Math.max(max, squares[i].value);
     }
  }
  return max;
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to accept an array of either `InternalSquare` or `SquareState`:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAygjgVwIYCcI2E40C8UDeAUFFAG5IA2CEAXFAHYIC2ARhCgDSEC+A3IYVCQoASXrYU9SvGRooeIiXJVaDZmxRQAPmooUufARAAeYAPYpgUAGYJ6AY2ABLM-SgBzCMACySYwAoAZ0RUCEC6AEEUFCQQAB4xCSkKGVDtWBC0DCwIAD4ASjpGVnYCYhIoNGAESShg2TCAOjQAEwR7CH9bB2dXfyQoIvV2DigWQdFxdmTUuR1Z9ExsQrUSzUUKkidrKH8WRuVqeRw8Rj18ss3Nqpq3JH4rqG4oCApA6A3Hm9rfYAALRpMPz9Ub7Q4QfIPK7ccokbijAAMkJ4AiAA))

```
type SquareState = {
  value: number,
};

type InternalSquare = {
  value: number | null,
};

export function getMax(squares: Array<InternalSquare | SquareState>): number {
    return squares.reduce(function(a : number, b : InternalSquare | SquareState): number {
      if (b.value === null) {
        return a;
      } else {
        return Math.max(a, b.value);
      }
    }, 0);
}
```

It doesn't seem like flow realizes that reducing the union of two arrays (`Array<A> | Array<B>`) is equivalent to reducing an array of the union of both types (`Array<A | B>`). This might even be PR-worthy.

Interestingly, spreading the array allows flow to understand the type as `Array<InternalSquare | SquareState>`:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAygjgVwIYCcI2E40C8UDeAUFFAG5IA2CEAXFAHYIC2ARhCgDSEC+A3IYVCQoASXrYU9SvGRooeIiXJVaDZmxRQAPmooUufARAAeYAPYpgUAGYJ6AY2ABLM-SgBzCMACySYwAoAZ0RUCEC6AEEUFCQQAB4xCSkKGVCAPm0oKJj41LQMLAg0gEo6RlZ2AmIoe1dAqyRrCRgwNCQAE3koAG0AOn7g2TCAXWqSNGAESShG5taIDt60doR7CH9bB2dXfyQoMvV2DigWfdFxdmS86B1rguxStQrNRRI3p2sofxZe5Wp5HB4Rh6YpVN7gqATKZuJD8CFQbhQCAUQLQV7wqHTXzAAAWvSYfl2xx+fwgxThEO4YwRxwADOSeAIgA))

```
type SquareState = {
  value: number,
};

type InternalSquare = {
  value: number | null,
};

export function getMax(squares: Array<InternalSquare> | Array<SquareState>): number {
    const afterSpread = [...squares]
    return afterSpread.reduce(function(a : number, b : InternalSquare | SquareState): number {
      if (b.value === null) {
        return a;
      } else {
        return Math.max(a, b.value);
      }
    }, 0);
}
```

Even more interesting, if you change one of the arrays (but not both!) to a $ReadOnlyArray, it also understands what's going on here:

```
type SquareState = {
  value: number,
};

type InternalSquare = {
  value: number | null,
};

export function getMax(squares: $ReadOnlyArray<InternalSquare> | Array<SquareState>): number {
    return squares.reduce(function(a : number, b : InternalSquare | SquareState): number {
      if (b.value === null) {
        return a;
      } else {
        return Math.max(a, b.value);
      }
    }, 0);
}
```

I'd hazard a guess that it actually evaluates each of the possibilities in that case and finds both possibilities work. Total speculation though.

Comment: Thanks so much! It turns out this is [probably a bug](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2264), too - so your comment about PR worthy is exactly right.